# Why when I define a variable in one function, it can't be accesed in another one

Tags: python

I am new to python and programming in general, so this may seem like a silly question. When I define a variable in one function, I can't access it in another function. For example:

```
def getname():
    name = raw_input("What is your name?")
    print("Ok," + name)

def getage(name):
    age = raw_input("What is you age," + name)
    print ("Great!")

getname()
getage()
```

When I run this it says "Global name 'name' is not defined". Sorry if this is a really stupid question. I have not really programmed before,
Thanks.

Comment: Imagine any name you ever used in any function being available in all other functions. Do you think that'd be practical and workable?

Comment: variables inside a function is of `local scope`. it has to use inside that function only

Comment: if you want to share variables use a class and attributes or return the variable in your function.

Comment: Perhaps you want to [read through the Python tutorial here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions); it'll teach such important concepts such as *returning* a value from a function.

Comment: Thanks, Ill read that tutorial now.

Comment: It's a fair and reasonable entry level question and doesn't merit the close votes. Let's all stop kicking the newbies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can return the `name` and pass that to the other function, variables in functions are local to the function they are declared in unless you use the `global` keyword but returning is a better option:

```
def getname():
    name = raw_input("What is your name?")
    print("Ok," + name)
    return name # return the name so we can use it later

def getage(name):
    age = raw_input("What is you age," + name)
    print ("Great!")


name = getname() # assign name to return value from getname
getage(name) # pass it to getage
```

The [python practice-book](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/getting-started.html#functions) has some nice tutorials.

Comment: Thanks! I tried something similar to that earlier but I didn't do something right.

Comment: No worries, check out the link. It has a lot of useful info and starts from the very basics up to some more advanced features.

Answer (score 1):

Variables can be defined to have a global or local scope. Using global variables, while it's not "wrong" per se, increases the overall coupling of your software, and makes it harder to maintain.

So, using local variables, lets you choose which variables you share among different pieces of software (functions, objects, whatever constructs your programming language provides), and which variables should remain private to that function.

If one function needs a variable of another function, you could consider having the first function returning that variable, and passing it to the second function as an input parameter. But, you should also consider if the two functions do not belong together in the first place.

Since you are new to programming, I recommend you google about coupling and cohesion, two software qualitities that are in the foundation of design decisions like these.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone! I got it and I think I understand it!