# Purchasing theme park tickets program in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

#### Problem

I have been trying to make a program which allows the user to buy tickets and then keeps a record of the tickets, which were purchased/recorded in a **csv** file.

I have problems writing to the **csv** file in `def proceed(1)`, receive an error:

> "name 'amChildTickets' is not defined"

I am aware that I am trying to call a variable from another function to `proceed(1)`, but not sure how I can use a variable, which is already defined in the 'mainTicketMenu'.

#### Code

```
def proceed1():
   proceed = input("Would you like to order more tickets? ")
   if proceed in ("yes", "Yes", "y", "Y"):
      mainTicketMenu()
   elif proceed in ("no", "No", "n", "N"):
      userNames = input("What are the full names of the people you are ordering tickets for? ")
      localTime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()) )
      with open("Purchases.csv", "a") as f:
         f.write(f"Names: {userNames}, Child tickets: {amChildTickets}, Adult tickets: {amAdultTickets}, Group Adult Tickets: {amGroupAdultTickets}, Family Tivkets: {anFamilyTickets} Date of purchase: {localTime}, UniqueID: {uniqueID}\n")
         f.close()
      #mainMenu()

def otherTickets1():
   otherTickets = input("Would you like to order other tickets? ")
   if otherTickets == "Yes" or otherTickets == "yes" or otherTickets == "y" or otherTickets == "Y":
      mainTicketMenu()
   elif otherTickets == "No" or otherTickets == "no" or otherTickets == "n" or otherTickets == "N":
      print(f"Your total cost is £{totalCost}")
      totalCost = float(00.00)

def mainTicketMenu():
   print(f"{bnum1} Welcome to Fantasialand Theme Park {bnum1}\n\
{bnum2} 1. Buying Adult Tickets {bnum4} \n\
{bnum2} 2. Buying Group adult tickets (2+) {bnum3} \n\
{bnum2} 3. Buying Child Tickets {bnum4} \n\
{bnum2} 4. Buying Family Tickets (10% off Child & Adult prices){bnum5}")
   global totalCost
   ticketChoice = input(f"Which tickets would you like to purchase? ")
   if ticketChoice == "1" or ticketChoice == "adult":
      print(f"The price of an adult ticket is £{adultTicket:0.2f}")
      amAdultTickets = int(input("How many tickets would you like to purchase? "))
      amAdultTicketsCost = amAdultTickets * adultTicket
      print(f"The total cost of your adult tickets will be £{amAdultTicketsCost:0.2f}")
      purchaseConf = input("Would you like to purchase these tickets? ")
      if purchaseConf == "yes" or purchaseConf == "Yes" or purchaseConf == "y" or purchaseConf == "Y":
         totalCost = totalCost + amAdultTicketsCost
         print(f"Your total cost so far is £{totalCost:0.2f}")
         proceed1()
      elif purchaseConf == "no" or purchaseConf == "No" or purchaseConf == "n" or purchaseConf == "N":
         otherTickets()


   elif ticketChoice == "2" or ticketChoice == "Group adult":
      print("With a group adult ticket, if you order 2+ adult tickets, \nthe price of adult tickets are reduced")
      print(f"The price of an adult ticket for 2+ adults is £{gadultTicket:0.2f}")
      amAdultTickets = int(input("How many adult tickets do you want? "))
      if amAdultTickets >= 2:
         amAdultTicketsCost = amAdultTickets * gadultTicket
         print(f"{amAdultTickets} Adult tickets will cost you £{amAdultTicketsCost:0.2f}")
         purchaseConf = input("Would you like to purchase these tickets? ")
         if purchaseConf == "yes" or purchaseConf == "Yes" or purchaseConf == "y" or purchaseConf == "Y":
            totalCost = totalCost + amAdultTicketsCost
            print(f"Your total cost so far is £{totalCost:0.2f}")
            proceed1()
         if purchaseConf == "no" or purchaseConf == "No" or purchaseConf == "n" or purchaseConf == "N":
            otherTickets()
      elif amAdultTickets < 2:
         print("Sorry the group adult ticket is only for 2 or more adults")


   elif ticketChoice == "3" or ticketChoice == "child":
      print(f"The price of a child ticket is £{childTicket}")
      amChildTickets = int(input("How many child tickets would you like to purchase? "))
      amChildTicketsCost = amChildTickets * childTicket
      print(f"The total cost of your child tickets will be £{amChildTicketsCost}")
      purchaseConf = input("Would you like to order these tickets? ")
      if purchaseConf == "yes" or purchaseConf == "Yes" or purchaseConf == "y" or purchaseConf == "Y":
         totalCost = totalCost + amChildTicketsCost
         print(f"Your total cost so far is £{totalCost:0.2f}")
         proceed1()
      if purchaseConf == "no" or purchaseConf == "No" or purchaseConf == "n" or purchaseConf == "N":
         otherTickets()


   elif ticketChoice == "4" or ticketChoice == "Family Ticket":
      print(f"The price of a child ticket is £{childTicket}")
      print(f"The price of an adult ticket is £{adultTicket}")
      print(f"With a family ticket, if you order 2+ adult tickets and 2+ child tickets you\nreceive a 10% discount")
      amChildTickets = int(input("How many child tickets would you like to purchase? "))
      if amChildTickets >= 2:
         amChildTicketsCost = amChildTickets * childTicket
         totalCost = totalCost + amChildTicketsCost 
         amAdultTickets = int(input("How many adult tickets would you like to purchase? "))
         if amAdultTickets >= 2:
            amAdultTicketsCost = amAdultTickets * adultTicket
            totalCost = totalCost + amAdultTicketsCost
            discount = totalCost * 10 / 100
            totalCost = totalCost - discount
            print(f"Your total cost with a 10% discount is £{totalCost:0.2f}")
            purchaseConf = input("Would you like to purchase these tickets? ")
            if purchaseConf == "yes" or purchaseConf == "Yes" or purchaseConf == "y" or purchaseConf == "Y":
               proceed1()
            if purchaseConf == "no" or purchaseConf == "No" or purchaseConf == "n" or purchaseConf == "N":
               otherTickets1()
         elif amAdultTickets < 2:
            print("Sorry, the family ticket is only for 2 or more adults")
      elif amChildTickets < 2:
         print("Sorry, the family ticket is only for 2 or more children")

def mainMenu():
   print(f"{bnum1} Welcome to Fantasialand Theme Park {bnum1}\n\
{bnum2} 1. Purchasing Tickets For Fantasialand Theme Park {anum1}\n\
{bnum2} 2. Searching For Past Purchases {anum2}")
   choice1 = input("What would you like to do? ")
   if choice1 == "1" or choice1 == "Purchasing Tickets" or choice1 == "purchasing tickets":
      mainTicketMenu()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why when I define a variable in one function, it can't be accesed in another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198253/why-when-i-define-a-variable-in-one-function-it-cant-be-accesed-in-another-one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of approaching this.

When proceed1 is called the ticket amount will be passed as input, then updating the appropriate ticket type. When your variables are defined within a function there called local variables. Local variables cannot be used by other functions outside the scope. But can be used as inputs to other functions or redefined globally. This link will explain better. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/

```py
#Global ticket list
ticketList = [0,0,0,0]

#inputs: ticket amounts for each type of ticket
def proceed1(amChildTickets,amAdultTickets,amGroupAdultTickets,anFamilyTickets):
   # update each ticket amount when called
   ticketList[0] += amChildTickets
   ticketList[1] += amAdultTickets
   ticketList[2] += amGroupAdultTickets
   ticketList[3] += anFamilyTickets
   proceed = input("Would you like to order more tickets? ")
   if proceed in ("yes", "Yes", "y", "Y"):
      mainTicketMenu()
   elif proceed in ("no", "No", "n", "N"):
      userNames = input("What are the full names of the people you are ordering tickets for? ")
      localTime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()) )
      with open("Purchases.csv", "a") as f:
         f.write(f"Names: {userNames}, Child tickets: {ticketList[0]}, Adult tickets: {ticketList[1]}, Group Adult Tickets: {ticketList[2]}, Family Tivkets: {ticketList[3]} Date of purchase: {localTime}, UniqueID: {uniqueID}\n")
         f.close()
      mainMenu()

def otherTickets1():
   otherTickets = input("Would you like to order other tickets? ")
   if otherTickets == "Yes" or otherTickets == "yes" or otherTickets == "y" or otherTickets == "Y":
      mainTicketMenu()
   elif otherTickets == "No" or otherTickets == "no" or otherTickets == "n" or otherTickets == "N":
      print(f"Your total cost is £{totalCost}")
      totalCost = float(00.00)

def mainTicketMenu():

   print(f"{bnum1} Welcome to Fantasialand Theme Park {bnum1}\n\
   {bnum2} 1. Buying Adult Tickets {bnum4} \n\
   {bnum2} 2. Buying Group adult tickets (2+) {bnum3} \n\
   {bnum2} 3. Buying Child Tickets {bnum4} \n\
   {bnum2} 4. Buying Family Tickets (10% off Child & Adult prices){bnum5}")
   global totalCost
   ticketChoice = input(f"Which tickets would you like to purchase? ")
   if ticketChoice == "1" or ticketChoice == "adult":
      print(f"The price of an adult ticket is £{adultTicket:0.2f}")
      amAdultTickets = int(input("How many tickets would you like to purchase? "))
      amAdultTicketsCost = amAdultTickets * adultTicket
      print(f"The total cost of your adult tickets will be £{amAdultTicketsCost:0.2f}")
      purchaseConf = input("Would you like to purchase these tickets? ")
      if purchaseConf == "yes" or purchaseConf == "Yes" or purchaseConf == "y" or purchaseConf == "Y":
         totalCost = totalCost + amAdultTicketsCost
         print(f"Your total cost so far is £{totalCost:0.2f}")
         proceed1(0,amAdultTickets,0,0) # pass the amount of tickets to proceed1 function
      elif purchaseConf == "no" or purchaseConf == "No" or purchaseConf == "n" or purchaseConf == "N":
         otherTickets()


   elif ticketChoice == "2" or ticketChoice == "Group adult":
      print("With a group adult ticket, if you order 2+ adult tickets, \nthe price of adult tickets are reduced")
      print(f"The price of an adult ticket for 2+ adults is £{gadultTicket:0.2f}")
      amAdultTickets = int(input("How many adult tickets do you want? "))
      if amAdultTickets >= 2:
         amAdultTicketsCost = amAdultTickets * gadultTicket
         print(f"{amAdultTickets} Adult tickets will cost you £{amAdultTicketsCost:0.2f}")
         purchaseConf = input("Would you like to purchase these tickets? ")
         if purchaseConf == "yes" or purchaseConf == "Yes" or purchaseConf == "y" or purchaseConf == "Y":
            totalCost = totalCost + amAdultTicketsCost
            print(f"Your total cost so far is £{totalCost:0.2f}")
            proceed1(0,0,amAdultTickets,0)
         if purchaseConf == "no" or purchaseConf == "No" or purchaseConf == "n" or purchaseConf == "N":
            otherTickets()
      elif amAdultTickets < 2:
         print("Sorry the group adult ticket is only for 2 or more adults")


   elif ticketChoice == "3" or ticketChoice == "child":
      print(f"The price of a child ticket is £{childTicket}")
      amChildTickets = int(input("How many child tickets would you like to purchase? "))
      amChildTicketsCost = amChildTickets * childTicket
      print(f"The total cost of your child tickets will be £{amChildTicketsCost}")
      purchaseConf = input("Would you like to order these tickets? ")
      if purchaseConf == "yes" or purchaseConf == "Yes" or purchaseConf == "y" or purchaseConf == "Y":
         totalCost = totalCost + amChildTicketsCost
         print(f"Your total cost so far is £{totalCost:0.2f}")
         proceed1(amChildTickets,0,0,0)
      if purchaseConf == "no" or purchaseConf == "No" or purchaseConf == "n" or purchaseConf == "N":
         otherTickets()


   elif ticketChoice == "4" or ticketChoice == "Family Ticket":
      print(f"The price of a child ticket is £{childTicket}")
      print(f"The price of an adult ticket is £{adultTicket}")
      print(f"With a family ticket, if you order 2+ adult tickets and 2+ child tickets you\nreceive a 10% discount")
      amChildTickets = int(input("How many child tickets would you like to purchase? "))
      if amChildTickets >= 2:
         amChildTicketsCost = amChildTickets * childTicket
         totalCost = totalCost + amChildTicketsCost
         amAdultTickets = int(input("How many adult tickets would you like to purchase? "))
         if amAdultTickets >= 2:
            amAdultTicketsCost = amAdultTickets * adultTicket
            totalCost = totalCost + amAdultTicketsCost
            discount = totalCost * 10 / 100
            totalCost = totalCost - discount
            print(f"Your total cost with a 10% discount is £{totalCost:0.2f}")
            purchaseConf = input("Would you like to purchase these tickets? ")
            if purchaseConf == "yes" or purchaseConf == "Yes" or purchaseConf == "y" or purchaseConf == "Y":
               proceed1(0,0,0,amAdultTickets)
            if purchaseConf == "no" or purchaseConf == "No" or purchaseConf == "n" or purchaseConf == "N":
               otherTickets1()
         elif amAdultTickets < 2:
            print("Sorry, the family ticket is only for 2 or more adults")
      elif amChildTickets < 2:
         print("Sorry, the family ticket is only for 2 or more children")


def mainMenu():
   print(f"{bnum1} Welcome to Fantasialand Theme Park {bnum1}\n\
   {bnum2} 1. Purchasing Tickets For Fantasialand Theme Park {anum1}\n\
   {bnum2} 2. Searching For Past Purchases {anum2}")
   choice1 = input("What would you like to do? ")
   if choice1 == "1" or choice1 == "Purchasing Tickets" or choice1 == "purchasing tickets":
       mainTicketMenu()
mainMenu()
```